# how to fix Error 503 Backend fetch failed?

Tags: varnish

screenshot:

[image]

how can I fix this?

Comment: Please post all relevant errors, details, questions as **text** not in an image

Comment: Thanks for comment,

If you not know just ignore it, don't panic & do not give advise to anyone,

It's golden rule of life

Comment: @SolankiYagnik, have you solve this error?

Answer (score -2):

The problem was in “clean_cache_by_tags” function in Magento. I think it’s an error clearing the cache in php7 & magento2.

solution define here http://www.sohaib.com/2016/07/17/magento-503-backend-fetch-failed/

Comment: And by doing that, you're effectively disabling full page cache. Nice, not.

Comment: and the link is dead

Comment: Updated link: https://www.sohaib.com/magento-2-12-varnish-error-503-backend-fetch-failed-solved-php-7-1-nginx-varnish-5-x/

Comment: Any news on this?